# For loop is avoiding to write the last key within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this,

```
 print(sample_dict)
 dict_items([('SAP', ['SAP_MM_1.gz', 'SAP_MM_2.gz']), ('LUF',['LUF_1.gz', 'LUF_2.gz'])])

 sample1    = {x:[sample_dict[x][0]] for x in sample_dict}

print(sample1)
 dict_items {'SAP': ['SAP_MM_1.gz'],
     'LUF': ['LUF_1.gz']}
```

And now, I need to write keys in the above `sample1` as doc file and this is what I tried.

```
 for sam in sample1.keys():
    doc  = sam + '.doc'
    doc  = open(doc, 'w')
    doc.write("A: [\n")
```

Now it created two files for `SAP` and `LUF`, but only SAP is written and other file is empty. For loop is somehow avoiding to write the last `key` in the `sample1`. I do not understand what is wrong here. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Post `sample_dict`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be a case of Python not flushing the stream. You should probably close the file after writing (or better yet, use context manager):

```
with open(doc, 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write('whatever')
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not closing the file after you have written to it. You can close it explicitly but it is easier just to use `with` because that will close the file even if the code fails.

```
 for sam in sample1.keys():
    doc  = sam + '.doc'
    with output as open(doc, 'w'):
        output.write("A: [\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should open two separate files before writing to it. My approach would be something like below:

```
for sam in sample1.keys():
    with open(sam + '.doc', 'w') as sam_doc:
        sam_doc.write("A: [\n")
```

**Explanation**

Opening a file using `with` statement closes the file automatically after updation.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a big list of files, so I think Its is better to use the `with` with a for loop

Comment: Edited the answer, per your requirement